# r-exams Questions about the same data on 2 separate xxx.Rmd files

Tags: r, r-exams

Using R exams, I am developing a pdf exam with several questions (hence several Rmd files) but the questions are connected and would use a dataset created in the first question file. Questions would not be amenable to a cloze format.

Is there a way to write the exercises so that the second exercise can access the data generated by the first exercise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a shared environment across the different exercises, in the simplest case the `.GlobalEnv`. Then you can simply do

```
exams2pdf(c("ex1.Rmd", "ex2.Rmd"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

and then both exercises will create their variables in the global environment and can re-use existing variables from there. Instead of the `.GlobalEnv` you can also create `myenv <- new.env()` and use `envir = myenv`.

For Rnw (as opposed to Rmd) exercises, it is not necessary to set this option because `Sweave()` Rnw exercises are always processed in the current environment anyway.

Note that these approaches only work for those `exams2xyz()` interfaces, where the n-th random draw from each exercise can be assured to end up together in the n-the exam. This is the case for PDF output but not for many of the learning management system outputs (Moodle, Canvas, etc.). See: [Sharing a random CSV data set across exercises with exams2moodle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018204/sharing-a-random-csv-data-set-across-exercises-with-exams2moodle)

Comment: Agreed this is easier. Thank you for the complementary link to previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

Is it an option to save the data you need to disk in one `Rmd` file

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
saveRDS(df, "my_stored_data.rds")
```
````

and then load it in the other one

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
readRDS(df, "my_stored_data.rds")
```
````

Comment: This solution works fine. I was just wondering whether there was a solution to avoid writing and reading from a file.

Comment: Look at the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Another option** could be to knit the `Rmd` files from an `R` script and then knit them from this `R` script. If you do that, the `Rmd` files *use the environment of the `R` script* (!) instead of creating their own. Hence you can use the same objects (and therefore of course let one `Rmd` script store the data, while the other uses it as input.

In this thread: [Create sections through a loop with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158486/create-sections-through-a-loop-with-knitr)
there is a post from me about doing this. It's basically this:

The first Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Script 1"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
a_data_frame_created_in_script_1 <- mtcars
```
````

saved as `rmd_test.Rmd`

The second one:

````
---
title: "Script 1"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
a_data_frame_created_in_script_1
```
````

saved as `rmd_test_2.Rmd`.

And then you have an R-script that does this:

```
rmarkdown::render("rmd_test.Rmd", output_file = "rmd_test.html")
rmarkdown::render("rmd_test_2.Rmd", output_file = "rmd_test_2.html")
```

Comment: Thanks for this additional tip. Would suspect this adds another layer of complexity in the writing of the exercises though.

Comment: Edited the answer.
Of course, I don't know your exercises, but I have the feeling, that this actually an elegant solution.